# IBM MQ :: Remote Configuration - Can't Start Sender Channel

Tags: networking, cmd, client, ibm-mq, host

I am working with IBM MQ. I managed to get a basic Handshake / Put Message(s) / Get Message(s) / Disconnect .net solution going on, a couple of days ago, but it only works on a local level, and I now need to update the solution so it works remotely as well.

After reading and experimenting for a while, I decided to follow [IBM Knowledge Center's Point to Point scenario](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sce.doc/q113940_.htm) step by step. However, I can't start the Sender Channel as instructed by the [guide's last step](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sce.doc/q113650_.htm); the Sender Channel's status ping-pongs between Binding and Retrying, and the logs come up with the following error codes; **AMQ9002**, **AMQ9202** and **AMQ9999**, meaning, as far as I can tell, there is some kind of trouble finding and/or connecting with the host, as explained by the error logs.

I have looked through a lot of questions regarding these errors in particular, but while I have followed most of the proposed solutions (*I made sure the Receiver's listener is running, I tried turning off Firewalls, I tried with different ports, I have performed tests Telnet, I have stopped/restarted/resolved the Sender channel a few times, and I have tried setting this up from both, the command line and MQ Explorer*), I have yet to get a successful communication going on between two different PCs.

I am aware the error could be either temporary, or the result of problems within the Network itself, but I have been trying to establish a successful connection for almost three days now, and before I pass this unto my bosses I would like to make sure I have exhausted every other possibility.

How can I complete IBM's Point To Point set up guide, or is there anything that could point me towards a different / better approach to get two PCs talking with each other via IBM MQ v9?

Although hastily translated from Japanese, you can find the detailed error logs below.

> 2017/09/19 17:34:09 - Process (234212.1) User (MUSR_MQADMIN) Program
>   (runmqchl.exe)
>                         Host (DESKTOP - UP 4 D 363) Installation (Installation 1)
>                         VRMF (9.0.3.0) QMgr (QM 1)
>                         Time (2017-09-19T08: 34: 09.201 Z)
>
> **AMQ9002:** Channel 'TO.QM2' is starting.
>
> Description: Channel 'TO.QM2' is starting.
>
> ACTION: None.

---

> 2017/09/19 17:34:30 - Process (234212.1) User (MUSR_MQADMIN) Program
>   (runmqchl.exe)
>                         Host (DESKTOP - UP4D363) Installation (Installation 1)
>                         VRMF (9.0.3.0) QMgr (QM 1)
>                         Time (2017-09-19T08: 34: 30.824Z)
>
> **AMQ 9202:** The remote host 'DESKTOP-1AV4LM3 (The correct ip address) (1415)' can not be used.Please try again later.
>
> Description: Using TCP / IP to host 'DESKTOP-1AV4LM3 (The correct ip
>   address) of channel TO.QM2 (1415) 'trying to allocate a conversation,
>   but it did not succeed. However, It is temporary and there is also the
>   possibility that TCP / IP conversation can be allocated normally
>   later.
>
> If the remote host can not be determined, '????' is displayed. .
>
> ACTION: Please try the connection later. If the failure persists,
>   record the error value Please contact the stem administrator. The
>   return code from TCP / IP is 10060 (X'274C ').The cause of this
>   failure may be that the host can not reach the destination host.
>   Alternatively, There is a possibility that the host 'DESKTOP-1AV4LM3
>   (The correct ip address) (1415)' listener isn't running. If that is
>   the case, start the listener and try again.

---

> 2017/09/19 17:34:30 - Process (234212.1) User (MUSR_MQADMIN) Program (runmqchl.exe)
>                         Host (DESKTOP - UP 4 D 363) Installation (Installation 1)
>                         VRMF (9.0.3.0) QMgr (QM 1)
>                         Time (2017-09-19T08: 34: 30.825Z)
>
> **AMQ9999:** Channel 'TO.QM2' for host 'DESKTOP-1AV4LM3 (1415)' terminated abnormally
>
> Description: The host 'DESKTOP-1AV4LM3 (1415)' cannot be determined.
>
> ACTION: Check the error log for the preceding error message for
>   this channel program Please determine the cause of failure....
>   ".

Comment: These errors are from the sender side, do you see any errors on the receiver side of the connection?  You stated *I have performed tests Telnet*, what was the result, could you connect successfully from the sender channel server to the receiver channel server?

Comment: Did you make sure any local windows firewall software is not blocking the outbound connection on the sender channel server or inbound on the receiver channel server?

Comment: I never even thought of looking at the receiver's side error log! I will definitely keep that in min for any future issues, thank you!. 
I turned the local windows firewall was off in both machines, and Telnet tests were successful.
It turns out, JasonE's suggestion was spot on, disabling reverse DNS lookups on both machines solved the issue and I was able to send messages from one pc to another!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'interesting' bit of the error messages above is that the sender is attempting to start a channel to port 1415 on the destination and is getting a 10060 return code (WSAETIMEDOUT). This is different from an immediate rejection because the other end doesnt have a socket open, for example.

You will also note its timing out after about 21 seconds if your times are to be believed. The only time I've seen this kind of things is DNS resolution - There was an APAR for example showing that reverse DNS can cause delays in channel startup, and this could be for a successful or unsuccessful startup
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC96408

A new attribute was added to MQ to disable reverse DNS lookups if its the cause - See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q113120_.htm#q113120___chlauth

If this is the case, on the receiving end (or both!) try runmqsc , 'ALTER QMGR REVDNS(DISABLED)'. You might have to restart the qmgr for it to be effective (I'm not sure, sorry)

I'd also echo the comment added to your question by JoshMc, to check the receiving end logs for messages (both global errors but more likely the qmgr specific AMQERR01.LOG files) when this occurs - I have a feeling that the timeout is only part of your problem.

Comment: disabling reverse DNS is worth a try, but I do not think it is the cause.  On Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 the default initial connect timeout is 21 seconds per [Hotfix 2786464](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2786464/hotfix-enables-the-configuration-of-the-tcp-maximum-syn-retransmission) it states `the TCP maximum SYN retransmission value is set to 2, and is not configurable. Because of the 3-second limit of the initial time-out value, the TCP three-way handshake is limited to a 21-second timeframe (3 seconds + 2*3 seconds + 4*3 seconds = 21 seconds).`

Comment: Disabling reverse DNS lookups on both machines did indeed solve the issue and I was immediately able to send messages from one machine to another. Thank you.

Comment: @Geoab - Great news. Bear in mind this will impact CHLAUTH rules if you want to use hostnames, so it would be worth trying to get the DNS sorted if you can, but in the meantime its working :-)

Comment: @JasonE - Thank you for point that out, I will definitely keep it mind when I start cleaning up the code and correctly setting Firewall exceptions as well, but, for the time being, I am celebrating that I just finished adjusting the C#, and everything is working there too :) - this is really not my area of expertise, so setting something up, even as simple as this, feels like a huge leap from what I knew a few days ago.
Thanks for helping me out so much, I couldn't have made it otherwise !